# How to delete first character from regex [JS]

Tags: javascript, regex

I managed to find and replace phone numbers with a very simple Java Script but need to delete the first character as easy as possible. Could anyone please give me an hint?

```
function cleanPhoneNumbers() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(
            /\(?(0[0-9]{2,4})\)?\-?\/?\ ?[-. ]?([0-9]{7})/g,
            "<a href='tel:+49$1$2'>$1-$2</a>"
        );
}
</script>
```

Comment: But, what if the first character is important? And what about your code doesn't work as expected? Perhaps provide before and after examples.

Comment: What do you mean by first character?

Comment: Note: Assigning to `document.body.innerHTML` will **completely destroy and then rebuild the page**. That means any event handlers attached to the old elements will not be attached to the new, replacement elements (unless old-fashioned `onXyz` attributes were used).

Comment: The first character isn't important because it's a phone number and the regex already just looks for phone numbers that begin with a 0. And I translate it to an international phone number, where the 0 is replaced by the +49. And thus I have to do it with every phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just modify your existing code so it looks like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cleanPhoneNumbers() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(
            /\(?(0[0-9]{2,4})\)?\-?\/?\ ?[-. ]?([0-9]{7})/g,
            "<a href='tel:+49$1$2'>$1-$2</a>"
        ).substring(1);
}
</script>
```

This updated code uses javascript **substring** command, the number 1 states where to start the string.  0 would be the whole string, 1 starts after the first character.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I had to add substring(1) somewhere but wasn't sure how and couldn't figure it out myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sadly it didn't work as expected. It just cuts the first line inside the body-tag.